# Explanation of pear's include path, and why Drush cr clears it?

Tags: 8

I got an error message when trying to import Drupal configuration with drush cim, saying the following:

include_once(/var/www/d8site/modules/custom/somemodule/somemodule.module):[warning]
failed to open stream: No such file or directory Extension.php:140
include_once(): Failed opening                                       [warning]
'/var/www/d8site/modules/custom/somemodule/somemodule.module' for
inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
Extension.php:140

The somemodule.module file was deleted between versions, but it's still expecting it.  Restarting and/or reloading Apache didn't get rid of this message, but drush cr did.  I don't want to have to clear the entire Drupal cache on production, so how could I update this include list without clearing all cache with drush?  If I didn't have pear installed, would this be any different?

Answer (score 3):

Pear has no connection to this. The error message displays the include path value in brackets for debugging purpose. You can check the value as follows:

```
drush ev 'print get_include_path();'
```

In your case the PHP is trying to include the file from this location and emits the error as it fails.
*/var/www/d8site/modules/custom/somemodule/somemodule.module*

My guess the file still presents in Drupal registry because the module wasn't uninstalled properly. Check out this guide to fix it. https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215

Comment: The module wasn't uninstalled, it's just that the .module file was no longer needed, so it was removed.  But, thank you for the info on Pear.

Comment: I would try to reinstall the module then.